# Best asymptotic notation

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

If an algorithm worst case running time is 6n^4 + 2, and its best case running time is 67+ 6n^3. What is the most appropriate asymptotic notation.

I'm trying learn about Big O notation.

is it Θ(n^2) ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming question

Comment: Neither your worst case nor your best case have asymptotic n^2 behavior. So it cannot be Θ(n^2) see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: You have formulas with n^3 and n^4. Where would n^2 come from ?

Comment: "What is the most appropriate asymptotic notation": for WHAT ?

Comment: Also what meaning do you give to "best" or "most appropriate" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, Big-Oh time complexity analysis is defined for best case, worst case or average number of operations algorithm performs. "is it Θ(n^2) ?" So, you should specify which case are you looking for? Or do you mean to say is it `Θ(n^2)` for all cases? (which is obviously not correct)

Having said that, we know that algorithm performs `6n^4 + 2` operations in worst case. So it has `Θ(n^4)` worst case complexity. I've used theta here because I know exactly how many operations are going to be performed. In the best case, it performs `67+ 6n^3` operations. So it has `Θ(n^3)` time complexity for the best case.

How about average time complexity? Well, I can't know as long as I am not provided with the probability distribution of the inputs. It's maybe the case that best-case-like scenario rarely occurs and average time complexity is `Θ(n^4)`, or vice versa. So we cannot directly infer the average time complexity from the worst/best case time complexities as long as we are not provided with input probability distribution, the algorithm itself or the recurrence relation. (Well, if best and worst time complexities are the same, then of course we can conclude that average time complexity is equal to them)

If algorithm is provided, we can calculate average time complexity making some very basic assumptions on the input (like equally likely distribution etc.). For example in linear search, best case is `O(1)`. Worst case is `O(n)`. Assuming equally likely distribution, you can conclude that average time complexity is `O(n)` using expectation formula. [sum of (probability of input i) * (number of operations for that input)]

Lastly, your average time complexity CANNOT be `Θ(n^2)` because your best and worst time complexities are worst than quadratic. It doesn't make sense to wait this algorithm perform n^2 operations in average, while it performs n^3 operations in best case.

Time complexity for best case <= time complexity for average <= time complexity for worst case

Comment: "claiming that an algorithm has Θ(n²) time complexity is wrong": let me disagree. An algorithm that has worst-case O(n²) and best case Ω(n²) can be said to have a Θ(n²) behavior.

Comment: I tried to point out that one should specify worst/best/average. Directly saying that "algorithm has x time complexity" doesn't seem to be an appropriate way of saying things. However, most of the cases we understand from such statements that algorithm has x average time complexity as in your example. It's computer science common sense I guess.

Comment: I am not sure you understood my point, and I was not concerned by the average case.

Comment: Ok, I'm confused a little bit. Do we discuss the semantics or the syntax? Because my problem is with syntax. I've said "Claiming that an algorithm has Θ(n²) time complexity is wrong", because we should say "an algorithm has best/worst/average Θ(n²) time complexity". If you talk about semantics, then ok, I completely agree with this statement:  "n algorithm that has worst-case O(n²) and best case Ω(n²) can be said to have a Θ(n²) behavior"

Comment: Ok, I guess you are saying that by this statement: "An algorithm that has worst-case O(n²) and best case Ω(n²) can be said to have a Θ(n²) behavior", you are claiming that time complexity of algorithm for all cases is Θ(n²) and therefore we can struct a sentence like this: "claiming that an algorithm has Θ(n²) time complexity is wrong", meaning that time complexity is always Θ(n²) regardless of the worst/best/average situation. Is it what you said?

Comment: Right. I agree that this is a little abuse, as usually the running time is not a univocal *function* of n but a whole distribution. It is also very common to say O(f(n)) time complexity instead of O(f(n)) worst-case time complexity.